# fields in JOOQ record not lining up when fetchInto

Tags: java, jooq

This is a weird problem that keeps happening across versions 3.10 and 3.11 of JOOQ (didn't try earlier versions).  I fetch a record using `fetchInto`, and when I print the record (or have debug on) the fields all print correctly.  That is to say the value for field_x is correct.

The problem is that when I go to retrieve field_x using the record's `getX` method, it returns the value from another field.

Below is some of the code we used.

```
        return jooqDslContext.select(CL_USERS.fields())
            .from(CL_USERS)
            .join(THIRDPARTY_USER_XREF)
            .on(THIRDPARTY_USER_XREF.USER_ID.eq(CL_USERS.CL_USER_ID))
            .join(THIRDPARTY_USER_ID)
            .on(THIRDPARTY_USER_ID.ID.eq(THIRDPARTY_USER_XREF.THIRDPARTY_ID))
            .where(THIRDPARTY_USER_ID.EID.eq(eid))
            .fetchOptionalInto(CL_USERS);
```

Here is the print of the record....

```
+--------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-----------+------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+ etc... 
|remember_token                                    |cl_user_id|ria_id|ria_user_id|ria_user_id_backup|cl_user_type|user_description|first_name              | etc...
+--------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-----------+------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+ etc...
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...| 777777777|   777|      77777|            {null}|      {null}|{null}          |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx| etc...
+--------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-----------+------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------
```

notice the `first_name` is populated.  but when i print the `first_name` using the `getFirstName` method I get `NULL`.

```
cur.getFirstName() = null
```

From the looks of it seems that there is a mismatch between the index number of the field.... the generated code thinks `firstName` is field 6, in this case, but in reality it is field 8 (the 8th field in the `toString()` output.

```
    public byte[] getFirstName() {
        return (byte[]) get(6);
    }
```

EDIT:  Adding more info.

> How can this be reproduced?

Here is another example using a different code base from the example above.  In this case I set the `amount` field on the record object.  But when I go to save it or print it out, the `address` field is set instead.

```
    TransactionsRecord tr = serviceDslContext.newRecord(Transactions.TRANSACTIONS);
    tr.setAmount(new BigDecimal(10));
    logger.debug("tr = {}", tr);
```

prints..

```
+------+-------+-------+...
|amount|account|address|...
+------+-------+-------+...
|{null}|{null} |*10    |...
+------+-------+-------+...
```

[Link to the JOOQ generated code.](https://github.com/jmart1/examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/jmart1/example/repo/service/model)

> Can you post the DDL of the table?

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
    `account` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(42,10) NOT NULL,
    `bip125-replaceable` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `blockhash` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `blockindex` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `blocktime` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `category` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `confirmation` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `generated` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `instantlock` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `involvesWatchonly` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `label` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `timereceived` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `txid` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `vout` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `walletconflicts` TEXT NULL,
    `amount_in_usd` DECIMAL(42,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `usd_exchange_rate` DECIMAL(42,10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`txid`),
    INDEX `account_generated` (`account`, `generated`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

> What database product and version are you using?

In the above case I am using MySQL 5.7.23 on AWS RDS.  For the first example it was a variant of MySQL 5.6 on AWS RDS.  Also, for the latter example, it has occurred on 5.7.14-google, we migrated recently to AWS.

Comment: Is there a mismatch between the generated record and the generated table? I.e. does the record reference as many columns as the table?

Comment: There are 44 fields in the record, and 44 columns in the table.  I also had this on a separate project this weekend but in that case a new record is created using the DslContext and assigned the values using setFieldName methods.  When I tried storing the record, the columns were not lined up to the fields.  To fix it, I switched to set(FIELD, value) method for setting the values of the record.

Comment: Sounds like a very weird edge case bug in the code generator. How can this be reproduced? Can you post the DDL of the table? What database product and version are you using?

Comment: @LukasEder added some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the generated record you've posted was modified manually or using some post processors, or it was generated by a custom generator. Clearly, the generated table (correct order):

```java
public class Transactions extends TableImpl<TransactionsRecord> {

    ...

    public final TableField<TransactionsRecord, BigDecimal> AMOUNT = 
      createField("amount", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.DECIMAL(42, 10).nullable(false), this, "");

    public final TableField<TransactionsRecord, String> ACCOUNT = 
      createField("account", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR(50).nullable(false), this, "");

    public final TableField<TransactionsRecord, String> ADDRESS = 
      createField("address", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR(50).nullable(false), this, "");

    ...
```

... and the generated record:

```java
public class TransactionsRecord extends UpdatableRecordImpl<TransactionsRecord> 
    implements Record20<...> {

    public void setAccount(String value) {
        set(0, value);
    }

    public String getAccount() {
        return (String) get(0);
    }

    public void setAddress(String value) {
        set(1, value);
    }

    public TransactionsRecord() {
        super(Transactions.TRANSACTIONS);
    }

    public TransactionsRecord(String account, String address, BigDecimal amount, ...) {
        super(Transactions.TRANSACTIONS);

        set(0, account);
        set(1, address);
        set(2, amount);
        ...
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return (BigDecimal) get(2);
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return (String) get(1);
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal value) {
        set(2, value);
    }

    public void setBlockhash(String value) {
        set(4, value);
    }

    ...
```

... don't match. Look at how there are getters and setters before *and* after the constructor. Also, they are not in order! The official `JavaGenerator` provided by jOOQ wouldn't generate such a class.

Notice, if you do want to modify generated code, you should either override `JavaGenerator` or implement your own generator class.

Comment: Oh wow I wonder if its caused by IntelliJ?  I only use the JOOQ generators.  But I know when I commit code, IntelliJ reformats, rearranges, cleanup, and optimizes imports... those are the various `Before Commit` options it has.

Comment: Going to do a fresh generation, test the code, then apply IntelliJ's post-processor, and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JoseMartinez: But that would only explain the different order, not the different indexes used in the getters and the constructor.

Comment: I think it does more than what we would expect an IDE should do.  My guess is the re-arrange code feature is the culprit.  The only generators I use are `org.jooq.util.GenerationTool ` for 3.10 or `org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool` for 3.11.  I'll have the results of my tests tonight.

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some testing it looks like the `Rearrange code` feature in IntelliJ is messing up the JOOQ generated code.  This can have dire consequences for code running in production.  The `Rearrange code` feature is displayed as an option in the Commit Changes window.

[image]

The testing consisted of running a test before and after the `Rearrange code` feature.  Below is the code.

```
    TransactionsRecord tr = serviceDslContext.newRecord(TRANSACTIONS);
    tr.setAmount(new BigDecimal(10));
    logger.debug("tr = {}", tr);
```

If this code is executed before the `Rearrange code` feature, that is right after JOOQ has generated the code, then the following is displayed...

```
 +-------+-------+------+...
|account|address|amount|...
+-------+-------+------+...
|{null} |{null} |   *10|...
+-------+-------+------+...
```

After IntelliJ executes `Rearrange code`on the JOOQ generated code, this is the output...

```
+------+-------+-------+...
|amount|account|address|...
+------+-------+-------+...
|{null}|{null} |*10    |...
+------+-------+-------+...
```

It seems like the values stay in the right spot, but the fields that those values represent have shifted around.

Comment: Great finding! Thanks for documenting this. I'd also raise a bug to IntelliJ. This is quite severe.